# issue with login using spring security configuration?

Tags: spring, spring-security

i am using spring security for authentication.i have two fields. email and password.
 i have below configuration:

```
**<form method="post" action="/j_spring_security_check" >**

two fields as email and passwords.

for email i gave name as j_email and for password i gave j_password.
```

and in security file i gave datasource to validate against table. but for valid email/password  i am getting **ERR:login.failed**. my question is does field names(j_email and j_passwords) does matter here? Please help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can specify inputs names in configuration:

```
<form-login username-parameter="j_email" password-parameter="j_password" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't have to change the "j_username" to "j_email".
Your fields should be like:
j_username : for email
j_password : for password

But if you want to have it with your own names, you should follow what *M.Hryszczyk* said.